# Where/How to store and check specific user limitations?

Tags: sql, django, database-design, django-rest-framework

I have a standard User, Group, Permission schema that use to grant/revoke CRUD permissions to my users. I have an API that serves filtered data from a model Data based on a user's query.

I want to have the ability to limit how many objects get returned when a user sends a query. My question is I'm not sure where/how to best store this information.

The basic solution I have is add a `max_rows` column to my Group and reference that every request It's simple and easy to manage, but since users can have multiple groups I'd have to make sure that `max_rows` is in sync with the other groups that user belongs to.

Any thoughts to improve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to ensure that your max rows are in sync accross the groups the user belongs to.

Think about it this way: superadmin should be able to acquire as many rows as he/she asks for, that's infinity. A trusted user may have some proper limit, like 10 000 rows maximum, for example. Now, if somebody has both roles, it is evident that the person should be able to load as many records as he/she wants, because he/she is a superadmin and the fact that the person is also trusted should not diminish his/her superadmin rights, therefore a logical approach would be:

```
select max(max_rows)
from yourgrouptable
join yourgroupmappingtable
on yourgrouptable.id = yourgroupmappingtable.group_id
where yourgroupmappingtable.user_id = 5;
```